# How to remove option selected with bs4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My idea of this script is to make a script that prints out the following

`4,5
5,5
6
7
8,5
9
10`

with using the following HTML of:

```
<select name="id" style="display: none;">
   <option value="-1" class="selected">
      Choose number
   </option>
   <option value="5011265">
      4,5
   </option>
   <option data-alt="1 kvar" value="5012834">
      5,5
   </option>
   <option value="5011266">
      6
   </option>
   <option value="5011267">
      7
   </option>
   <option data-alt="1 kvar" value="5011269">
      8,5
   </option>
   <option value="5011270">
      9
   </option>
   <option value="5011271">
      10
   </option>
</select>
```

I managed to print out using

```
nosto_sku_tags = bs4.find_all('select', {'name': 'id'})

    product_skus = []
    for nosto_sku_tag in nosto_sku_tags:

        try:
            sku_size = nosto_sku_tag
            print(sku_size)

        except Exception:
            sku_size = None
```

However the print out I am getting are:

Choose number
   
   
      4,5
   
   
      5,5
   
   
      6
   
   
      7
   
   
      8,5
   
   
      9
   
   
      10

and I have no idea how I can continue with my code to produce so it only prints out all of the numbers but not the first one which is `Choose number`.

How can I make the code so it prints out only the numbers without having the `Choose number` included?

Result print out when printing right now:

```
<select name="id">
   <option value="-1">
      Choose number
   </option>
   <option value="5011265">
      4,5
   </option>
   <option data-alt="1 kvar" value="5012834">
      5,5
   </option>
   <option value="5011266">
      6
   </option>
   <option value="5011267">
      7
   </option>
   <option data-alt="1 kvar" value="5011269">
      8,5
   </option>
   <option value="5011270">
      9
   </option>
   <option value="5011271">
      10
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can't have printed out all of the options shown in the *sample HTML*, because that sample html uses `<li>` elements, not `<option>` elements. Can you please show your actual code or HTML?

Comment: Oh for sure! One moment!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is that better :) ?

Comment: No, not really. `bs4.find_all('option')` produces a list of `<option>` elements (provided that `bs4` is a `BeautifulSoup` element). Your HTML doesn't *have* any `<option>` elements, only `<li>` elements.

Comment: You'd have to use `.select('li.option')` to select the `<li>` elements that have a `'option'` class set.

Comment: Oh, Basically the reason I did was that this was the only `option` that is in the html. So my idea was to print out all the options using `bs4.find_all('option')` - That was my thought but it might be bad way?

Comment: You state that the code you posted *[...] printed out all of them including the first one*. The code *can't do that* because the code you posted would only work with `<option>` HTML elements. The HTML you posted has no such elements, only `<li>` elements. So there is a discrepancy here, you made a claim that can't be reproduced with the information you posted here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I cant quite get what you mean, Basically whenever I run the code that I posted, I get this print (Will edit in post) - Which means that somehow I do get all the options including the first one.

Comment: There may well be *actual `<option>` elements in the HTML*, but you didn't include those in your post. You are misunderstanding what has been found by the `.find_all()` call. Please provide all the information to reproduce your issue *in the question*. When you use `bs4 = BeautifulSoup('''<html you posted in your question''')` then `bs4.find_all('option')` produces an empty list. So I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Alright I will try to re-write and see. I will provide all the information I get all over again and say exactly what I do :) 5 min!

Comment: @MartijnPieters I found a better HTML which I hope now provide better result, I have written now everything and I hope it is better said now :)

Comment: Not *quite*, but it is a lot closer. Your code selects the `<select>` tags, then loops as if you have the child `<option>` tags. But the intent is clear.

Comment: Oh, I just printed out the results I get. My thought was, maybe somehow if the option value is -1, then skip it? Since I assume the `Choose number` is always -1 as value so.... ?

Comment: My answer below still applies, just test for the class.

Comment: You continue to post results that *don't match*. Note the `<option value="-1" class="selected">` in the sample HTML versus what you printed below. Where did the `class` go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'selected' you mean that the first one has the `selected` *class*, you can simply test for that:

```
nosto_sku_tags = bs4.select('select[name="id"] option')
for nosto_sku_tag in nosto_sku_tags:
    if 'selected' in nosto_sku_tag.get('class', ()):
        continue
    sku_size = nosto_sku_tag.get_text(strip=True)
```

(There is really no need to use exception handling in this case, all tags have a `get_text()` method).

Because the `class` attribute could be *missing*, you need to use `.get('class', ())` to get an empty tuple instead in that case.

Note that I used a *different query* to find the `<option>` elements you posted in the HTML. Your code prints the `<select>` element, as one big object, not the individual `<option>` elements under it. Rather than use a separate search for the `<select>` element and then the `<option>` elements contained, I used a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to directly go to the options.

The BeautifulSoup CSS selector code isn't all that sophisticated, so we can't use the `:not(.selected)` psuedo selector to filter out that one option.

Demo:

```
>>> nosto_sku_tags = soup.select('select[name="id"] option')
>>> for nosto_sku_tag in nosto_sku_tags:
...     if 'selected' in nosto_sku_tag.get('class', ()):
...         continue
...     sku_size = nosto_sku_tag.get_text(strip=True)
...     print(sku_size)
...
4,5
5,5
6
7
8,5
9
10
```

If there is *no* class on the `<option>` elements, and there is no `selected` attribute either, then you'll have to come up with your own heuristics. By default the *first* element is the one that is visible in the browser, so we can just skip that one:

```
for nosto_sku_tag in nosto_sku_tags[1:]:
    sku_size = nosto_sku_tag.get_text(strip=True)
```

Note the `[1:]` slice.

Comment: Hmm I tried that but it didn't print anything at all, Was just blank when I tried that strangely.

Comment: @CDNthe2nd: yes, that's because your HTML and the search do not match.

Comment: I don't think it supposed to work since `if 'selected` but there is no `selected` anymore in the code as you can see from the top post

Comment: @CDNthe2nd: right, then just skip the first, as that's the default in this case.

Comment: @CDNthe2nd: also, I copied your HTML; your sample input and output don't match, clearly.

Comment: Thats strange, I did exactly use that HTML and used exactly that code as I provided which gave me an output from what I provided at the top but since we are so close I believe, What am I supposed to do now? Because the code you provided gives me `Choose number` included.

Comment: @CDNthe2nd: did you copy the HTML from your browser perhaps? Take into account that that reflects the current DOM, which can have been altered by Javascript code! When I use your first sample, I get `<option class="selected" value="-1">` included, so the `class` test works. Your code prints the `<select>` element, and that shows the class is *not* there, so you didn't use the same HTML.